# ruby application aws data loss after eb deploy in ec2 instance

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my rails application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk following this tutorial (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html).

But now when I deploys new version (using command $ eb deploy) instead of updating the application it resets my all data. 
I don't know how to update minor changes, even in html file.
I also tried DeleteOnTerminate = false, but not working.

Is there any method so I can update my application without losing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not make it clear how you are saving your data, but the first thing you need to understand is that Elastic Beanstalk applications run in an ephemeral state by nature.

This means that whenever you use eb deploy the "server" running your application is completely destroyed and another one is brought up instead.

The only way to keep your data persistent between different deploys is by using a source outside the app like S3 or a database, and have the app query the data from there.

Comment: They don't run on Docker containers, but everything else you said is correct.

Comment: True that, we ran docker containers in our environment and so I assumed it's part of the standard beanstalk configuration, but now I see there are other options too. I've edited my answer, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I'm just saving a model which has two strings you can visit my application (http://xyzurl.com) . But don't know how to save it outside the app like S3.

Comment: Persisting your data is not rhat complicated but is outside the scope of this question, I suggest reading about ways to integrate your ruby app with S3 or RDS and then implementing the way you see fit into your app.

Comment: Here is the documentation for the aws s3 sdk for ruby, you can use that to save your data in s3 - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

Comment: Thank for help , I just save the data outside in a RDS and it's working now.